# Is Multi-layered SRWLock Valid?

Tags: c++, winapi

For Example, is this code valid?

```
SRWLOCK srwLockA;
SRWLOCK srwLockB;

::InitializeSRWLock( &srwLockA);
::InitializeSRWLock( &srwLockB);

::AcquireSRWLockExclusive( &srwLockA );      // First level

/* do some stuff with member A*/

::AcquireSRWLockExclusive( &srwLockB );      // Second level

/* do some stuff with member A & B */

::ReleaseSRWLockExclusive( &srwLockB );        // Second level

/* do some stuff with member A**/

::ReleaseSRWLockExclusive( &srwLockA );      // First level
```

srwLockA and srwLockB are meant to protect member A and B separately.
I am just wondering SRWlock can used in this way.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Reason I doubt is because of this line in its document

"An SRW lock is the size of a pointer. The advantage is that it is fast to update the lock state. The disadvantage is that very little state information can be stored, so SRW locks cannot be acquired recursively. In addition, a thread that owns an SRW lock in shared mode cannot upgrade its ownership of the lock to exclusive mode."

I do not fully understand what "acquired recursively means"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

"Acquiring a lock recursively" means acquiring *the same lock* twice. Example:

```
SRWLOCK lock;
::InitializeSRWLock( &lock );

::AcquireSRWLockExclusive( &lock ); // acquire the lock
// Now we have the lock
::AcquireSRWLockExclusive( &lock ); // acquire the lock again!?
// Now we still have the lock

::ReleaseSRWLockExclusive( &lock ); // release the lock
// Now we STILL have the lock?
::ReleaseSRWLockExclusive( &lock ); // release the lock again
// Now we don't.
```

This does not work for SRW locks. It does work for some types of locks, such as mutexes (of course, for a mutex you would use `WaitForSingleObject` and `ReleaseMutex` instead of `AcquireSRWLockExclusive` and `ReleaseSRWLockExclusive`).

You can acquire more than one unrelated lock, as they don't know anything about each other.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer, @immibis
I suppose mutilayering critcal section works as well yes?

Comment: @Control Yes. In general, different locks don't know anything about each other. (That also means you could e.g. acquire a SRW lock inside a critical section)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, my reading of it (not 100% guaranteed to be correct until tested):

- SRWLock can be acquired in the same thread while another SRWLock in the same thread is already acquired
- SRWLock cannot be re-acquired in the same thread while *the same* SRWLock is already acquired in the same thread; most likely, such attempt for recursive acquiring of the same lock will lead to infinite self-deadlock (similar to non-recursive mutexes in *nix).